# Expect test of exit code in exit trap to be non-zero if exit due to variable check

Tags: bash, shell

I expect the following script to exit by writing a non-zero integer to the screen, but it actually writes `0`. If I comment out `trap exiting EXIT`, run, and then execute `echo $?` from the console, I get what I expect, a non-zero exit code. I'd expect both flows to return the same non-zero exit code. For example, if I uncomment `exit 10` then both flows, with and without the trap, print `10`.

Is this a bug with variable testing?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function exiting {
    echo $?
}
trap exiting EXIT

# exit 10

: ${foo?'where is foo?'}
```

Comment: I can't repro the stated behavior. See https://ideone.com/PvXrEz -- it writes `1`, not `0`. This implies that it already _has_ been raised upstream and fixed, unless you're running a newer bash release than the 5.0.3 build that ideone.com presently is. To which point: What release _are_ you running?

Comment: Yep. That's it! I was running the default version that comes with OSX. I discovered I didn't have the `declare -g` option which prompted me to check the version and upgrade using these instructions https://itnext.io/upgrading-bash-on-macos-7138bd1066ba. Thanks for running my repro, and for the ideone link. What a great resource! Much appreciated!